# Convert Dictionary to JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, serialization

I have create the next Dictionary:

```
var postJSON = [ids[0]:answersArray[0], ids[1]:answersArray[1], ids[2]:answersArray[2]] as Dictionary
```

and I get:

```
[2: B, 1: A, 3: C]
```

So, how can I convert it to JSON?

Comment: [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html)

Comment: Or [`JSONEncoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder) with [custom types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types). See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Answer (score 313):

**Swift 3.0**

With Swift 3, the name of `NSJSONSerialization` and its methods have changed, according to the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

```
let dic = ["2": "B", "1": "A", "3": "C"]

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted)
    // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

    let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
    // here "decoded" is of type `Any`, decoded from JSON data

    // you can now cast it with the right type        
    if let dictFromJSON = decoded as? [String:String] {
        // use dictFromJSON
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

---

**Swift 2.x**

```
do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dic, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
    // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

    let decoded = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
    // here "decoded" is of type `AnyObject`, decoded from JSON data

    // you can now cast it with the right type 
    if let dictFromJSON = decoded as? [String:String] {
        // use dictFromJSON
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

---

**Swift 1**

```
var error: NSError?
if let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dic, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error) {
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    } else {
        // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data
    }
}

if let decoded = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as? [String:String] {
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    } else {
        // here "decoded" is the dictionary decoded from JSON data
    }
}
```

---

Comment: I get the next `[2: A, 1: A, 3: A]`. But what about curly brackets?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What curly brackets? You asked about encoding a dictionary in JSON, and that's my answer.

Comment: JSON curly brackets, like `{"result":[{"body":"Question 3"}] }`

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade The above call to `dataWithJSONObject` _would_ produce the "curly brackets" (i.e. the braces) as part of the resulting `NSData` object.

Comment: thanks. side note - consider using d0 instead to abbreviate (dic)tionary.

Answer (score 211):

You are making a wrong assumption. Just because the debugger/Playground shows your dictionary in square brackets (which is how Cocoa displays dictionaries) that does not mean that is the way the JSON output is formatted.

Here is example code that will convert a dictionary of strings to JSON:

Swift 3 version:

```
import Foundation

let dictionary = ["aKey": "aValue", "anotherKey": "anotherValue"]
if let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(
    withJSONObject: dictionary,
    options: []) {
    let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,
                               encoding: .ascii)
    print("JSON string = \(theJSONText!)")
}
```

To display the above in "pretty printed" format you'd change the options line to:

```
    options: [.prettyPrinted]
```

Or in Swift 2 syntax:

```
import Foundation
 
let dictionary = ["aKey": "aValue", "anotherKey": "anotherValue"]
let theJSONData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
  dictionary ,
  options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0),
  error: nil)
let theJSONText = NSString(data: theJSONData!,
  encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
println("JSON string = \(theJSONText!)")
```

The output of that is

```
"JSON string = {"anotherKey":"anotherValue","aKey":"aValue"}"
```

Or in pretty format:

```
{
  "anotherKey" : "anotherValue",
  "aKey" : "aValue"
}
```

The dictionary is enclosed in curly braces in the JSON output, just as you'd expect.

### EDIT:

In Swift 3/4 syntax, the code above looks like this:

```
  let dictionary = ["aKey": "aValue", "anotherKey": "anotherValue"]
    if let theJSONData = try?  JSONSerialization.data(
      withJSONObject: dictionary,
      options: .prettyPrinted
      ),
      let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,
                               encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {
          print("JSON string = \n\(theJSONText)")
    }
  }
```

Comment: A regular Swift string works as well on theJSONText declaration.

Comment: @thefredelement, How do you convert NSData directly to a Swift string though? The data to string conversion is a function of NSString.

Comment: I was implementing this method and used the data / encoding init on a Swift string, I'm not sure if that was available on Swift 1.x.

Comment: Neither your description of your problem nor your code make much sense.

Comment: @VyTcdc My code in the answer? Or was this intended for the OP?

Comment: this is changing sequence of keys how to prevent sequence while converting string to json?

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora I am not sure what you are trying to ask, and adding a comment to an answer that's almost a year old is not a good idea. Post a new question.

Comment: why to post a new question if I am getting solution in same question answer and having only doubt in it

Comment: Because (1) that is how you are supposed to ask questions on SO. You don't have a "doubt". You are asking a new question in a comment to an answer.

Comment: (2) your question is incoherent. I think I understand what you are trying to ask but it is not a grammatical sentence. Create a question with sample data, the result you expect, and what you get instead.

Answer (score 91):

**Swift 5:**

```
let dictionary = ["2": "B", "1": "A", "3": "C"]
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(dictionary) {
    if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(jsonString)
    }
}
```

Note that keys and values must implement `Codable`. Strings, Ints, and Doubles (and more) are already `Codable`. See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Also note that `Any` does not conform to `Codable`. It is likely still a good approach to adapt your data to become `Codable` so that you are making use of Swift typing (especially in the case that you are also going to decode any encoded json), and so that you can be more declarative about the outcome of your encoding.

Comment: Just for the future reference, this solution won't work if your dict is of type [String, Any]

Comment: Agreed, but for the sake of future readers, it should be noted that `[String: Any]` is a bit of an anti-pattern, nowadays. Generally we would use [custom types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types) rather than `[String: Any]`. That offers better strongly-typed code with better compile-time validation. And we’d then encode it with `JSONEncoder`. Sometimes (with legacy code, especially that which integrates with Objective-C) we have to use `JSONSerialization`, but `JSONEncoder` is definitely the preferred solution nowadays.

Answer (score 38):

My answer for your question is below

```
let dict = ["0": "ArrayObjectOne", "1": "ArrayObjecttwo", "2": "ArrayObjectThree"]

var error : NSError?

let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

print(jsonString)
```

Answer is

```
{
  "0" : "ArrayObjectOne",
  "1" : "ArrayObjecttwo",
  "2" : "ArrayObjectThree"
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Swift 4 `Dictionary` extension.

```
extension Dictionary {
    var jsonStringRepresentation: String? {
        guard let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self,
                                                            options: [.prettyPrinted]) else {
            return nil
        }

        return String(data: theJSONData, encoding: .ascii)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good and reusable way of solving the problem but a little explanation would help new comers to understand it better.

Comment: Could this be applied if keys of the dictionary contains array of custom objects?

Comment: It is not good idea to use `encoding: .ascii` in public extension. `.utf8` will be much safer!

Comment: this prints with escape characters is there anywhere to prevent that?

Answer (score 30):

Sometimes it's necessary to print out server's response for debugging purposes. Here's a function I use:

```
extension Dictionary {

    var json: String {
        let invalidJson = "Not a valid JSON"
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: .prettyPrinted)
            return String(bytes: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? invalidJson
        } catch {
            return invalidJson
        }
    }

    func printJson() {
        print(json)
    }

}
```

Example of use:

```
(lldb) po dictionary.printJson()
{
  "InviteId" : 2,
  "EventId" : 13591,
  "Messages" : [
    {
      "SenderUserId" : 9514,
      "MessageText" : "test",
      "RecipientUserId" : 9470
    },
    {
      "SenderUserId" : 9514,
      "MessageText" : "test",
      "RecipientUserId" : 9470
    }
  ],
  "TargetUserId" : 9470,
  "InvitedUsers" : [
    9470
  ],
  "InvitingUserId" : 9514,
  "WillGo" : true,
  "DateCreated" : "2016-08-24 14:01:08 +00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 5:**

```
extension Dictionary {
    
    /// Convert Dictionary to JSON string
    /// - Throws: exception if dictionary cannot be converted to JSON data or when data cannot be converted to UTF8 string
    /// - Returns: JSON string
    func toJson() throws -> String {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self)
        if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            return string
        }
        throw NSError(domain: "Dictionary", code: 1, userInfo: ["message": "Data cannot be converted to .utf8 string"])
    }
}
```

Comment: This work well for Codable types, but be careful with String: Any, this will produce incorrect value !

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3**:

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [])
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonString)
```

Comment: This will crash if any part is nil, very bad practice to force unwrap the results. // Anyway there's already the same information (without the crash) in other answers, please avoid posting duplicate content. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 5.4

```
extension Dictionary {
    var jsonData: Data? {
        return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: [.prettyPrinted])
    }
    
    func toJSONString() -> String? {
        if let jsonData = jsonData {
            let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
            return jsonString
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

The idea of having it as a variable is because then you can reuse it like that:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func decode<T:Codable>() throws -> T {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData ?? Data())
    }
}
```

Comment: This work well for Codable types, but be careful with String: Any, this will produce incorrect value !

Comment: @Wo_0NDeR which property or method will produce incorrect values?

Answer (score 5):

Answer for your question is below:

**Swift 2.1**

```
     do {
          if let postData : NSData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictDataToBeConverted, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted){

          let json = NSString(data: postData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
          print(json)}

        }
        catch {
           print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy extension to do this:

https://gist.github.com/stevenojo/0cb8afcba721838b8dcb115b846727c3

```
extension Dictionary {
    func jsonString() -> NSString? {
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: [])
        guard jsonData != nil else {return nil}
        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
        guard jsonString != nil else {return nil}
        return jsonString! as NSString
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

using `lldb`

```
(lldb) p JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: notification.request.content.userInfo, options: [])
(Data) $R16 = 375 bytes
(lldb) p String(data: $R16!, encoding: .utf8)!
(String) $R18 = "{\"aps\": \"some_text\"}"

//or
p String(data: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: notification.request.content.userInfo, options: [])!, encoding: .utf8)!
(String) $R4 = "{\"aps\": \"some_text\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 do{
        let dataDict = [ "level" :
                            [
                                ["column" : 0,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 0,"up" : 0],
                                ["column" : 1,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 0,"up" : 0],
                                ["column" : 2,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 0,"up" : 0],
                                ["column" : 0,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 1,"up" : 0],
                                ["column" : 1,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 1,"up" : 0],
                                ["column" : 2,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 1,"up" : 0]
                            ]
        ]
        var jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        let jsonStringData =  NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
        print(jsonStringData)
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import SwiftyJSON

extension JSON {
    
    mutating func appendIfKeyValuePair(key: String, value: Any){
        if var dict = self.dictionaryObject {
            dict[key] = value
            self = JSON(dict)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var data: JSON = []

data.appendIfKeyValuePair(key: "myKey", value: "myValue")
```

Answer (score 0):

**2022, swift 5**

usage of extensions:

Encode:

```
if let json = statisticsDict.asJSONStr() {
     //your action with json
}
```

Decode from Dictionary:

```
json.decodeFromJson(type: [String:AppStat].self)
    .onSuccess{
        $0// your dictionary of type: [String:AppStat]
    }
```

extensions:

```
@available(macOS 10.15, *)
public extension Encodable {
    func asJson() -> Result<String, Error>{
        JSONEncoder()
            .try(self)
            .flatMap{ $0.asString() }
    }
}

public extension String {
    func decodeFromJson<T>(type: T.Type) -> Result<T, Error> where T: Decodable {
        self.asData()
            .flatMap { JSONDecoder().try(type, from: $0) }
    }
}

///////////////////////////////
/// HELPERS
//////////////////////////////

@available(macOS 10.15, *)
fileprivate extension JSONEncoder {
    func `try`<T : Encodable>(_ value: T) -> Result<Output, Error> {
        do {
            return .success(try self.encode(value))
        } catch {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension JSONDecoder {
    func `try`<T: Decodable>(_ t: T.Type, from data: Data) -> Result<T,Error> {
        do {
            return .success(try self.decode(t, from: data))
        } catch {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension String {
    func asData() -> Result<Data, Error> {
        if let data = self.data(using: .utf8) {
            return .success(data)
        } else {
            return .failure(WTF("can't convert string to data: \(self)"))
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension Data {
    func asString() -> Result<String, Error> {
        if let str = String(data: self, encoding: .utf8) {
            return .success(str)
        } else {
            return .failure(WTF("can't convert Data to string"))
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func WTF(_ msg: String, code: Int = 0) -> Error {
    NSError(code: code, message: msg)
}

internal extension NSError {
    convenience init(code: Int, message: String) {
        let userInfo: [String: String] = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:message]
        self.init(domain: "FTW", code: code, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private func convertDictToJson(dict : NSDictionary) -> NSDictionary?
{
    var jsonDict : NSDictionary!

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:dict, options:[])
        let jsonDataString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        print("Post Request Params : \(jsonDataString)")
        jsonDict = [ParameterKey : jsonDataString]
        return jsonDict
    } catch {
        print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
        jsonDict = nil
    }
    return jsonDict
}
```

Comment: Several mistakes here. Why using Foundation's NSDictionary instead of Swift's Dictionary?! Also why returning a new dictionary with a String as value, instead of returning the actual JSON data? This doesn't make sense. Also the implicitly  unwrapped optional returned as an optional is really not a good idea at all.