# Swift: Convert struct to JSON?

Tags: json, swift, struct, nsjsonserialization

I created a `struct` and want to save it as a JSON-file.

```
struct Sentence {
    var sentence = ""
    var lang = ""
}

var s = Sentence()
s.sentence = "Hello world"
s.lang = "en"
print(s)
```

...which results in:

```
Sentence(sentence: "Hello world", lang: "en")
```

But how can I convert the `struct` object to something like:

```
{
    "sentence": "Hello world",
    "lang": "en"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Dictionary to JSON in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625133/convert-dictionary-to-json-in-swift) (as a hint, you can only convert an array or dictionary to JSON, so basically you need a dictionary representation of the value you want to put in JSON format).

Comment: Essentially, it would be great if I could convert the struct to a json-like String. When only arrays and dictionaries are convertable to JSON, my question is: How to convert a struct to a dictionary?

Comment: There are 3rd party libraries such as https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper. I have no experience with that, however.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Swift 4 introduces the `Codable` protocol which provides a very convenient way to encode and decode custom structs.

```
struct Sentence : Codable {
    let sentence : String
    let lang : String
}

let sentences = [Sentence(sentence: "Hello world", lang: "en"), 
                 Sentence(sentence: "Hallo Welt", lang: "de")]

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(sentences)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(jsonString) // [{"sentence":"Hello world","lang":"en"},{"sentence":"Hallo Welt","lang":"de"}]
    
    // and decode it back
    let decodedSentences = try JSONDecoder().decode([Sentence].self, from: jsonData)
    print(decodedSentences)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: How can we reconvert it to struct?

Comment: @BhavinRamani Add an initializer init(dict: [String:Any]) {...` and extract the values

Comment: @BhavinRamani, you can do it automatically, here is a great tutorial: https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=1562

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 4** supports the Encodable protocol e.g.

```
struct Sentence: Encodable {
    var sentence: String?
    var lang: String?
}

let sentence = Sentence(sentence: "Hello world", lang: "en")
```

Now you can automatically convert your Struct into JSON using a JSONEncoder:

```
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(sentence)
```

Print it out:

```
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
print(jsonString)

{
    "sentence": "Hello world",
    "lang": "en"
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Answer (score 13):

Use the [NSJSONSerialization class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/).

Using this for [reference](https://matt.sh/swiftly-types-05), you may need to create a function which returns the JSON serialized string. In this function you could take the required properties and create a NSDictionary from them and use the class mentioned above.

Something like this:

```
struct Sentence {
    var sentence = ""
    var lang = ""

    func toJSON() -> String? {
        let props = ["Sentence": self.sentence, "lang": lang]
        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(props,
            options: .PrettyPrinted)
            return String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        } catch let error {
            print("error converting to json: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

Because your struct only has two properties it might be easier to just build the JSON string yourself.

Comment: The return of `toJSON()` should be `NSData`.  Also, the second key in the `props` dictionary you've created is wrong.

Comment: I've updated the second key to be a string, thanks. The second point depends on what the user wants returning

Answer (score 11):

Here's a nice extension and a method for JSON encoding/decoding:

```
extension Encodable {
    
    func toJSONString() -> String {
        let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        return String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
    
}

func instantiate<T: Decodable>(jsonString: String) -> T? {
    return try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!)
}
```

Sample usage:

```
struct Sentence: Codable {
    var sentence = ""
    var lang = ""
}

let sentence = Sentence(sentence: "Hello world", lang: "en")
let jsonStr = sentence.toJSONString()
print(jsonStr)      // prints {"lang":"en","sentence":"Hello world"}

let sentenceFromJSON: Sentence? = instantiate(jsonString: jsonStr)
print(sentenceFromJSON!)    // same as original sentence
```