# struct to json like Stringify in javascript

Tags: json, swift

How can you convert a struct to json. Like Stringify in javascript?

Following gives the error: Argument type 'MyStruct' does not conform to expected type 'AnyType.
 
I get that, but how would you do it?

```
struct MyStruct{
    var name: String
}

let obj = MyStruct(name: "Bob")

let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(obj, options: .PrettyPrinted)
if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
    print(string)
}
```

Comment: First, read this: [Swift: Convert struct to JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186051/swift-convert-struct-to-json)

Comment: Then have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625133/convert-dictionary-to-json-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a function or property to your struct that gives you a dictionary that you then can serialise.

```
struct MyStruct{
    var name: String
    var dictionary: [String: AnyObject]{
        get {
            return ["name": name]
        }
    }
}
```