# How to convert NSDictionary to Json String in Swift ( iOS, Xcode )?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I'm suffering from the following problem....
My  `NSDictionary` is like that :

```
var dic : NSDictionary = [ "level" :
    [
        ["column" : 0,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 0,"up" : 0],
        ["column" : 1,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 0,"up" : 0],
        ["column" : 2,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 0,"up" : 0],
        ["column" : 0,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 1,"up" : 0],
        ["column" : 1,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 1,"up" : 0],
        ["column" : 2,"down" : 0,"left" : 0,"right" : 0,"row" : 1,"up" : 0]
    ]
]
```

But If I print this,

```
print(dic);  or print(“\(dic)”);
```

The Out put Is like that :

```
{
    level =     (
                {
            column = 0;
            down = 0;
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            row = 0;
            up = 0;
        },
                {
            column = 1;
            down = 0;
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            row = 0;
            up = 0;
        },
                {
            column = 2;
            down = 0;
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            row = 0;
            up = 0;
        },
                {
            column = 0;
            down = 0;
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            row = 1;
            up = 0;
        },
                {
            column = 1;
            down = 0;
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            row = 1;
            up = 0;
        },
                {
            column = 2;
            down = 0;
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            row = 1;
            up = 0;
        }
    ); }
```

How Can I get exact Json String? 
In swift, xcode?

Comment: Simple solution Please Check : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29628000/3378413

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No need to implement this kind of complex logic,

You can simply do this

```
var jsonData: NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error)!
if error == nil {
    return NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
}
```

and if you want to send it with API to server , no need to even convert it to String

Comment: Yes. This worked.... Thank you...

Comment: Look also here for swift 3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625483/5790492