# Array of type AnyObject to JSON array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I'm trying to generate a **Json** Array like this:

```
{
  "PaymentItems": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "paid": false
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "paid": false
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "paid": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using the following code:

```
var transacciones_modificacion = [Transacctions]()
var elementos = [AnyObject]()
for item in transacciones_modificacion
{
  let jsonObjectPaid: [AnyObject]  = [[ "id": item.Id, "paid":item.Paid]] 
  elementos.append(jsonObjectPaid)    
}

let pagosArray = ["PaymentItems": [elementos]]
```

Anybody knows how can I see the **json** data sent to my server?
thanks

Comment: `let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(newCompanyArray, options: nil) let JSONStringVisualization = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:   NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) printf(JSONStringVisualization)`?

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29625483/2227743

Comment: Yes, that works perfect! Thanks