# Crash : Convert dictionary to Json string in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift3

I'm trying to convert my swift dictionary to Json string but getting strange crash by saying

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'

My code:

```
let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "firstname": "aaa",
            "lastname": "sss",
            "email": "my_email",
            "nickname": "ddd",
            "password": "123",
            "username": "qqq"
            ]

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted)
    // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

    let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
    // here "decoded" is of type `Any`, decoded from JSON data

    // you can now cast it with the right type
    if let dictFromJSON = decoded as? [String:String] {
        // use dictFromJSON
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Please help me!

Regards.

Comment: “My code” comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625483/2227743

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**String** is not of type **AnyObject**.  Objects are *reference types*, but **String** in swift has *value semantics*.  A **String** however, can be of type **Any**, so the code below works.  I suggest you read up on reference types and value semantic types in Swift; its a subtle but important distinction and its also different from what you expect from most other languages, where String is often a reference type (including objective C).

```
    let jsonObject: [String: Any] = [
        "firstname": "aaa",
        "lastname": "sss",
        "email": "my_email",
        "nickname": "ddd",
        "password": "123",
        "username": "qqq"
    ]

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted)
        // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

        let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
        // here "decoded" is of type `Any`, decoded from JSON data

        // you can now cast it with the right type
        if let dictFromJSON = decoded as? [String:String] {
            print(dictFromJSON)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: try is handled by the catch clause