# Can't login to my database using Xcode

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, xcode

I am trying to login a user using a mysql database and php. I can successfully login the user when I use a browser, but cannot do so when I enter the exact same credentials into the Xcode simulator. Any help is much appreciated. Here's my code:

```
    @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let email = emailTxt.text!.lowercased()
    let password = passwordTxt.text



    let url = NSURL(string: "omitted")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let body = "email=\(email)&password=\(password)"

    request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in

        if error == nil {

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                guard let parseJSON = json else {
                    print("Error while parsing")
                    return
                }

                print(parseJSON)

                let id = parseJSON["id"] as? String

                if id != nil {

                    //successfully logged in

                }

            } catch {
                print("Caught an error: \(error)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }


    }).resume()





}
```

Here are the two php scripts I am using:

```
    <?php

//STEP 1. Check variables passing to this field via POST
$email = htmlentities($_REQUEST["email"]);
$password = htmlentities($_REQUEST["password"]);

if (empty($email) || empty($password)) {

    $returnArray["status"] = "400";
    $returnArray["message"] = "Missing required information";
    echo json_encode($returnArray);
    return;
    }

//STEP 2. Build Connection

$host = ommitted;
$username = omitted;
$pass = omitted;
$name = omitted;

// include access.php to call func from access.php file 
require("secure/access.php");
$access = new access($host, $username, $pass, $name);
$access->connect();


//STEP 3. Get user info
$user = $access->getUser($email);

if (empty($user)) {

    $returnArray["status"] = "403";
    $returnArray["message"] = "User is not found";
    echo json_encode($returnArray);
    return;
}

//STEP 4. Check Validity of entered password
//get password and salt from db
$secured_password = $user["password"];
$salt = $user["salt"];

//check if passwords match
if ($secured_password == sha1($password . $salt)) {

    $returnArray["status"] = "200";
    $returnArray["message"] = "Logged in successfully";
    $returnArray["id"] = $user["id"];
    $returnArray["email"] = $user["email"];
    $returnArray["ava"] = $user["ava"];
} else {
    $returnArray["status"] = "403";
    $returnArray["message"] = "passwords do not match";
}

//Step 5. Close connection
$access->disconnect();

//STEP 6. throw back all info to user
echo json_encode($returnArray);


?>
```

And the other:

```
    <?php

//Declare class to access this php file
class access {

    //connection global variables
    var $host = null;
    var $user = null;
    var $pass = null;
    var $name = null;
    var $conn = null;
    var $result = null;

    // constructing class
    function __construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) {

    $this->host = $dbhost;
    $this->user = $dbuser;
    $this->pass = $dbpass;
    $this->name = $dbname;

    }

    // Connection Function
    public function connect() {

        //establish connection and store it in $conn
        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);

        //if error
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo 'Could not connect to database'.mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        //support all languages
        $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");

    }

    //disconnection function
    public function disconnect() {

        if ($this->conn != null) {
        $this->conn->close();
        }

    }

    //Insert user details
    public function registerUser($email, $password, $salt) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO capstone_users SET email=?, password=?, salt=?";
        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

        if(!$statement) {
            throw new Exception($statement->error);
        }

        $statement->bind_param("sss", $email, $password, $salt);

        $returnValue = $statement->execute();

        return $returnValue;
    }

    public function selectUser($email) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM capstone_users WHERE email='".$email."'";

        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

        if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1 )) {
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            if (!empty($row)) {
                $returnArray = $row;
            }

        }

        return $returnArray;

    }

    //getting user information
    public function getUser($email) {

        $returnArray = array();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM capstone_users WHERE email='".$email."'";
        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

        if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            if (!empty($row)) {
                $returnArray = $row;
            }


        }

        return $returnArray;
    }


}


?>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like PHP. Maybe you're missing that associated code and a Swift tag as well.

Comment: You'll also want to properly URI-encode those variables. If a password contains `&`, which is highly probable, it will wreck your body string.

Comment: Thanks I changed the tags. Also the php script works fine. The error I am getting when I enter the correct email and password into the simulator is "passwords do not match" which I know is wrong because it matches exactly what is in my database. The password is encrypted so maybe that's where my problem is?

Comment: Without knowing what the PHP code is expecting it's really hard to say what you're doing wrong here other than my observation about the encoding being absolutely necessary.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the php scripts.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a broken hash like SHA1**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: First question I have is can you post your login request as a JSON-encoded body? That might simplify things if you have JSON in, JSON out.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new at programming and am following an online course. How would I implement JSON in and JSON out?

Comment: No worries. I'm just flagging this before you dig yourself into a hole that's difficult to escape from, or think this code is safe to go live with. There's a lot of dangers out there. As for the JSON part, [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625133/convert-dictionary-to-json-in-swift) seems like a good place to start, and on the PHP side [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). This avoids a lot of ugly `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` wrangling.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I'm going to try to implement what you just told me and will come back if I have problems.

Comment: have you added `App Transport Security Settings` in your plist?