# JSON Array with string and boolean

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I am creating a xCode/Swift project with `.json`.

I want to create an array of keys, and also a boolean(true/false) to mark if the key is used or not. Standard boolean value is `false`. And if the key is used, it updates to `true`. I am not sure how to do this, but I have tried something like this:

```
{
    "aloUrl": "fb://profile/********",
    "imgAD_active": true,
    "keys"{
        "key_red": false // if key "key_red" is used, set to true
        "key_green": false
        "key_black": false
        "key_white": false
        "key_orange": false
        "key_pink": false
    }
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use dictionary contains of `String` as keys and `Any` as values

```
let dic: [String: Any]
dic["aloUrl"] = "fb://profile/********"
dic["imgAD_active"] = true
dic["keys"] = ["key_green": false, "key_red": false, ...]
```

I also retrieve values as

```
let url = dic["aloUrl"] as? String
```

Comment: What should my `.json` file look like?

Comment: then you may check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625483/1485833 
to convert it to a JSON string.
after that you might want it to store it into .json file you can look at this for reading and writing to a file https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098149/1485833