# JSON Dictionary to String?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Is there a solution in Swift to have the value of these 2 key/value pairs in String ?

```
"ignoredentities":{"actualite":[68533]},
"lastentities":{"actualite":{"uid":3942,"starttime":1504850580},"video":{"uid":4392,"starttime":1504956600}},"count":25}
```

I want to have 2 String like :

```
let ignoredentities = "{"actualite":[68533]}"

let lastentities = "{"actualite":
{"uid":3942,
  "starttime":1504850580
},"video":
{"uid":4392,
  "starttime":1504956600
}
},"count":25}"
```

Comment: `(NS)JSONSerialization` can transform `(NS)Data` into `(NS)Array`/`(NS)Dictionary` and vice-versa. `(NS)Data` can be transform into `(NS)String` (UTF8) and vice-versa. So yes, it's possible, just look for each transformation one by one on SO.

Comment: Where is that JSON coming from and in what type is it stored? Have you already parsed it to a Dictionary?

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes it comes from a Dictionary, I tried String(describing: pagination["lastentities"]) but I got "Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x7c089d40>(\n\n)\n)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Dictionary to JSON in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625133/convert-dictionary-to-json-in-swift)

Comment: @ValentinGarcia so you actually want to store the JSON as a String with all the `{` and `[` symbols instead of properly parsing the JSON and storing it's values such as `actualite = 68533`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor exactly, I want a String that equals `" {"actualite" : [68533]} "`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: reqDict, options: .prettyPrinted)
                let reqJSONStr = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON Dictionary to String:

```
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
print("dataString = \(dataString!)")
```