# How to get JSON object from another JSON object in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift

how can I get applicationStateJson in below code, I can parse the bellow JSON object from data but can not able to get applicationStateJson from it

```
{
applicationStateJson =     {
    "address_status" = 0;
    email = "xxxxxxxx;
    "email_status" = 0;
    "first_name" = xxx;
    "last_name" = "";
    "login_status" = 1;
    loginstype = "<null>";
    mobile = xxxxxx;
    "mobile_status" = 1;
    notifications =         (
    );
    "notifications_size" = 0;
    "otp_status" = 3;
    "profile_id" = "<null>";
    "profile_name" = "virtual_recruiter";
    "user_id" = 454;
    "user_status" = 1;
    "virtual_recruiter_id" =xxx;
};
"error_msg" = "<null>";
status = "<null>";
}
```

code as

```
do { 
 let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject 
print(json) 
let applicationStateJson = try json["applicationStateJson"] 
} catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
```

Comment: show your tried code always

Comment: do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                        print(json)
                        let applicationStateJson = try json["applicationStateJson"]
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Dictionary to JSON in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625133/convert-dictionary-to-json-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code

First you need to change in below line, its `Dictionary<String, Any>` not an `AnyObject`

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
```

And then get **applicationStateJson**  by below code

```
if let appJson = json["applicationStateJson"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
    print(appJson)
    print("Email : \(appJson["email"] as? String ?? "Email not found")") // For get email
}
```

Comment: one more clarification from you that is how can I get a string("email_status") from JSON object

Answer (score 0):

The root object of the JSON is a clearly a dictionary, not `AnyObject` (an object but *I-have-no-idea-what-it-is*).

The value for key `applicationStateJson` is a dictionary, too.

```
do { 
   if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any],
      let applicationStateJson = json["applicationStateJson"] as? [String:Any] {
         print(applicationStateJson)
   }
} catch { 
   print(error)
}
```

As always, `.mutableContainers` is completely meaningless in Swift