# Convert nested JSON to Data object in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift

I have to send a URLRequest containing a JSON object as its http-body (which needs to be of type Data).

My JSON looks like this:

```
let json: [String : Any] = [
        "to" : toDeviceToken,       // String
            "notification" : [
                "title" : title,    // String
                "body" : body,      // String
                "icon" : icon       // UIImage
            ],
            "data" : {
                // Add optional data here.
            }
        ]
```

And I would like to convert this to type Data in order to put it into a URLRequest.

This

```
try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

always fails for some reason, maybe because it is a nested JSON object?
In addition, `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(json)` returns false.

When turning the UIImage object into a String object like this
`UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage.appIcon!)?.base64EncodedString()`, I get an error saying `'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'`

How would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Dictionary to JSON in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625133/convert-dictionary-to-json-in-swift)

Comment: `try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ...`

Comment: @LouFranco This does not work for me, maybe because it's a nested JSOn object?

Comment: The `UIImage` is the problem. The problem with your string conversion is that you used `?`, which means it's an `Optional` and cannot be represented either. You have to unwrap that optional which is the base64 string representation of the PNG.

Comment: FYI, people often use multipart/form-data requests when uploading an image, as the base64 string representation introduces 33% overhead. If it's a small image, that's inconsequential. But if it's a large image or if you're uploading many, it can start to become material. Tools like Alamofire make uploading multipart/form-data requests really easy. But if doing it manually, the code is a little more tedious.

Comment: I would also suggest using JPEG representation which will reduce considerably the data size

Comment: Uh...Did nobody see this or was is too obvious? After replacing the curly braces with the angular braces (see "data"), everything works. I also had to convert the image to a base64-encoded string, as you told me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because it contains data that can't be converted to JSON.

See the documentation for `JSONSerialization` for a list of support data types. Note that `UIImage` is not one of the supported types.

You will need to convert the `UIImage` to a string using a base64 encoding of its JPG or PNG representation.

Comment: UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage.appIcon!)?.base64EncodedString()         So this code should work, but it always throws a very long error 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'