# How to create JSON using Entity to POST in Swift3 iOS?

Tags: ios, json, post, swift3, httprequest

I am newly to Swift programming. I have to send below JSON request to server using httpRequest in Swift3.

```
{
    "CompanyId": 162,
    "RollupYear": 2018,
    "UserId": 1609,
    "datarollup": [{
            "Name": "Thank You Cards",
            "RollupYear": 2018,
            "DataRollupColumnID": 210,
            "CurrentValue": 520
        },
        {
            "Name": "Prospecting Calls",
            "RollupYear": 2018,
            "DataRollupColumnID": 212,
            "CurrentValue": 1300
        }
    ],
    "Seasonalitylist": [{
            "CompanyPeriodId": 386,
            "UserId": 1609,
            "Seasonality": 25
        },
        {
            "CompanyPeriodId": 387,
            "UserId": 1609,
            "Seasonality": 25
        }
    ]
}
```

So, in order to send JSON in this format I have created an Entity Class with name 'RequestModel' :

```
import Foundation

class RequestModel {

    var CompanyId: Int? = 0
    var RollupYear: Int? = 0
    var UserId: Int? = 0

    var dataRollupArr = NSMutableArray()
    var seasonalityArr = NSMutableArray() 
}

class DataRollupModel {
    var Name: String? = ""
    var CurrentValue: Float? = 0.0
    var RollupYear: Int? = 0
    var DataRollupColumnID: Int? = 0
}

class SeasonalityModel {

    var CompanyPeriodId: Int? = 0
    var UserId: Int? = 0
    var Seasonality: Int? = 0 
}
```

I have all my values, Can anyone suggest me how to add my Entity values to required JSON.

Note:

Here is my code to send JSON request to server for Login :

```
func login(email:String, password:String, completion:@escaping (NSDictionary) -> ()) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: baseurl+"login") {
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest( url: url as URL)

            let signInDict = ["UserName":email,"Password":password]

            print(signInDict)

            let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: signInDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("732rguiqfw9237ryu4k2141", forHTTPHeaderField: "KEY")

            request.httpBody = jsonData
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                data, response, error in
                do{
                    if let data = data,
                        let jsonString =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                        , error == nil {
                        completion(jsonString)
                    } else {
                        print("error=\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        let errorDict = ["error_status":true,"message":error!.localizedDescription] as [String : Any]
                        completion(errorDict as NSDictionary)

                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print("error=\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    let errorDict = ["error_status":true,"message":error.localizedDescription] as [String : Any]
                    completion(errorDict as NSDictionary)

                }

            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use NSStuff in Swift

Answer (score 2):

Hi first of all you don't have to create object if you already have a dictionary of the data you can directly convert it to json [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625133/convert-dictionary-to-json-in-swift)

I would suggest you to use object mapper as thats the easiest way if you still want to use object models

[Object mapper widely used](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)

The structs or objects that inherit the mappable class they have direct function to convert object to jsonString or the dictionary

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Kunal, Can you share me some code for my Modal and JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Swift 4** **Codable**, **#simple** like

```
class RequestModel: Codable {

    var CompanyId: Int? = 0
    var RollupYear: Int? = 0
    var UserId: Int? = 0

    var datarollup = [DataRollupModel]()
    var Seasonalitylist = [SeasonalityModel]()

    class DataRollupModel: Codable {
        var Name: String? = ""
        var currentValue: Float? = 0.0
        var RollupYear: Int? = 0
        var DataRollupColumnID: Int? = 0
        var CurrentValue: Int? = 0
    }

    class SeasonalityModel: Codable {

        var CompanyPeriodId: Int? = 0
        var UserId: Int? = 0
        var Seasonality: Int? = 0
    }

}

extension Encodable {
    func toJSONData() -> Data? {
        return try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }
}
```

Use

```
let instance = RequestModel()
let jsonData = instance.toJSONData()
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @SPatel Please see my edit, I want to know that I have values for all. Can you show me how can I pass my values to this Modal.