# I'm unable to upload array of objects in multipart using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to upload multipart form data using alamofire
I have two image and one array of object in params and I'm unable to upload array of object in multipart.
Here is my code ->

```
        let request = AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
        for (key, value) in params {
            if let temp = value as? String {
                multiPart.append(temp.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
          
            if let temp = value as? NSArray {
                temp.forEach({ element in
                    let keyObj = key + "[]"
                    if let string = element as? String {
                        multiPart.append(string.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: keyObj)
                    }
                    else if let dict = element as? [String:Any] {
                        // **Here I'm stuck & getting error -> No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'**

                        multiPart.append(dict, withName: keyObj)
                    }
     
                })
            }
            
            
            if let temp = value as? UIImage {
                multiPart.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
                multiPart.append(temp.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "file/png")

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to append Data here not dict or anything else in (multiPart.append(dict, withName: keyObj))

Comment: Need to convert all parms in data ?

Comment: and no need to check string or int or array ?

Comment: @asdfdfhj
You can try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625483/17286292

Comment: Did you succeed in uploading one image? If yes, what's that code? Does your WebAPI allow multiple uploads? If you had to manually write the params (with no for loop), how you'd do it? Does it works then?