# How to make a Data representation from a list of parameters for a POST method (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, networking, httprequest, urlrequest

Say I have the following API Service:

```
enum HttpMethod: Equatable {
    case get([URLQueryItem])
    case put(Data?)
    case post(Data?)

    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .get: return "GET"
        case .put: return "PUT"
        case .post: return "POST"
        }
    }
}

struct Request<Response> {
    let url: URL
    let method: HttpMethod
    var headers: [String: String] = [:]
}

extension Request {
    var urlRequest: URLRequest {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        switch method {
        case .post(let data), .put(let data):
            request.httpBody = data
        case let .get(queryItems):
            var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
            components?.queryItems = queryItems
            guard let url = components?.url else {
                preconditionFailure("Couldn't create a url from components...")
            }
            request = URLRequest(url: url)
        default:
            break
        }

        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpMethod = method.name
        return request
    }
}
```

How can I compose a `Data` representation from a list of parameters that I can POST?

```
extension Request {
    static func postEvent(type: String, title:String, tableId:Int? = nil, params: [String:Any]?) -> Self {
        Request(
            url: URL(string: NetworkingConstants.EVENTS)!,
            method: .post(
                // WHAT GOES HERE?
                // How to compose Data representation JSON?
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on what the server accepts, doesn't it? What format does the server need the data to be in? JSON? XML? Something else?

Comment: Let's assume JSON.

Comment: Well then it's a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29625133/5133585).

Comment: That answer focuses on `JSONSerialization`. Generally [`JSONEncoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder) with [custom types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types) that are [`Encodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable) might be preferable. See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Comment: As an aside, it would be best practice to set the `Content-Type` header for your `POST` requests. E.g., for `POST` with JSON body, we might specify a `Content-Type` of `application/json`. Depending upon the framework your backend is using, it might accept different types of payloads, so it is prudent to set the `Content-Type` header. FWIW, some web services would expect `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests (which obviously require client to encode the `httpBody` differently).

Comment: @Rob I tried adding `headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"` before the `request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers` line, but `Cannot assign through subscript: 'self' is immutable`. Where should this go?

Comment: I’d probably do it right were I encode the values, e.g., perhaps something like https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/31daba0c0bf3d46ed26a17e3603b5eb8.

Comment: @Rob that's helpful, thanks. I'm still struggling with the original question though. My latest attempt is `method: .post(
    try? JSONEncoder().encode(params)
   )` but `Type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Encodable'`

Comment: In `postEvent`, rather than `[String: Any]`, the `params` should be declared as `Encodable`.

Comment: I just want to be able to send any dictionary of params in my API calls though. There's got to be a way to do this without creating a new `Encodable` object for every new endpoint, right?

Comment: Using `Any` is a bit of an anti-pattern, and we generally would use `Encodable` types so that you enjoy compile-time validation of our parameters. But if you don’t want to tackle that right now, feel free to use `JSONSerialization` instead of `JSONEncoder`.